# Определить, какой примитивный коллайдер из составного коллайдера столкнулся с объектом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть обьект(1), он сталкивается с другим обьектом(2), коллайдер у которого составной. Как узнать с каким коллайдером обьекта(2) столкнулся обьекст(1)?

Answer (score -1):

Я не профи или не понял вопроса, но думаю так: создать тэг, этот тэг выбрать для дочернего объекта(2), у которого коллайдер. В скрипте объекта(1) прописать:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
if(collision == GameObject.FindWithTag("тут тэг, который вы создали"))
{
   тут логика
}
```

P.S возможно где-то неправильно написал код, но суть думаю ясна.

Comment: Если 2D игра, то OnCollisionEnter2D

Comment: Довольно сложно понять ваш ответ, но в целом поиск составного коллайдера по тэгам - возможная реализация, но уж никак не среди **всех** объектов в сцене.